# How to prevent wall trim-sheets seams in Unity 3D URP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, game-development, lighting, modular

Please take a look at the image. I have two planes touching, and I want to avoid seams in URP.

What is the best practice to mitigate this problem?

I tried, changing A-Aliasing in URP settings, and adding flaps to the edge of planes(extruding a bit on the sides of a plane), but I would like not to add more geometry. The level is only an indoor scene, with no environmental lighting.

[image]

Comment: I can't tell if the seam comes from the texture or if it is two separate planes.

Comment: Two planes, touching with edges.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the partial solution
The problem was that my UV was up to the edge and leaving some pixels and giving a bleed to a texture semi-fixed the problem. The seams are not visible from 2 unit but are from far...

The Final Solution -- give UV much more space 16-20px between islands and edges of texture!!!

Comment: FYI This practice is called leaving a margin. also don't forget to accept your own answer, so others can see that it's solved.